# Mongodb find documents with given field value inside an array and its id in another array inside the same document

Tags: javascript, mongodb

My data model:

```
{
 _id: ObjectId,
 persons:[{
  _id: ObjectId,
  name: String,
  ...
 }],
 relations: [{
  type: String,
  personId: ObjectId,
  ...
 }],
 ...
}
```

Here's my issue:
I am trying to find documents where person's name is x and it's _id is inside the relations array (personId) with a given type.

**Example**:

**My data:**

```
[{
 _id:"1",
 persons:[{
   _id:"1",
   name: "Homer"
 },
 {
   _id:"2",
   name: "Bart"
 }],
 relations: [{
   type:"House_Owner",
   personId: 1,
 }],
}]
```

**Request_1:**
*Find all documents where "Homer" is the house owner*

**Result:**

```
[{
 _id:"1",
 ...
}]
```

**Request_2:**
*Find all documents where "Bart" is the house owner*

**Result:**

```
[]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

The only solution I see here is to do the find operation with the given name value and after that filter the mongodb result.

PS: I cannot change the existing data model

**EDIT:**
I found a solution to do this by using $where operator with a javascript function but I am not sure that's the most efficient way.

```
db.myCollection("x").find({
   $where: function() {
     for (const relation of this.relations) {
       if(relation.type === "House_Owner") {
         for (const person of this.persons) {
            if(person.name === "Homer" && person._id.equals(relation.personId)) {
              return true;
            }
         }
       }
     }
  }
})
```

Comment: include the output result if possible

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
const requiredName="x"
const requiredId = "id"
await yourModel.find({$and:[{"relations.personId":requiredId },{"persons.name":requiredName}]})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that I want to query the relations.personId with the Id of each person matching the given name.
Sorry I wasn't clear but each person is only unique inside the document.

Comment: I will describe the wanted result with an example